# rEFind_x64.efi is showing inside rEFInd?

Tags: dual-boot, refind

Few weeks ago installed my first Linux distro, Mint and managed to set-up rEFInd with it.
Then I decided to switch to Pop_OS. I formatted the partition that I had both Mint and rEFInd on and installed Pop instead. Since rEFInd got unistalled, I installed it back using `sudo apt install refind`, the same way I did when I was on Mint.

But then I got this problem. After a successful install, **I rebooted to rEFInd to find that it is showing rEFind_x64.efi as a possible boot option.**

[image: refind1]

**Once I hit enter, it booted into my old, customized rEFInd that was stored in the deleted partition along with mint.**

[image: refind2]

When I tried to take a screenshot in rEFInd suing F10 I got this error.

[image: error]

I can boot Windows from both, but Pop only works in the second (the old one that should not exist).
I already tried unistalling and reinstalling, didn't help.
**Does anyone know where that rEFind_x64.efi is stored? Any help is really appreciated :)!**

Answer (score 0):

The "new" rEFInd indicates the location of the "old" one as:

```
Boot EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi from EFI system partition
```

Boot into Pop_OS and run `sudo efibootmgr -v`. Note the `BootCurrent:` line identifying the number of your current boot option, and read the `BootNNNN*` line with the corresponding number.  That line should tell you the PARTUUID of the EFI System Partition (ESP for short) used to boot the system, and the exact pathname of the "new" rEFInd within it. Use `lsblk -o +PARTUUID` to find out which disk the PARTUUID maps to. If you can't make sense of the outputs, please **edit your question** to add the outputs of the two above-mentioned commands to it.

I would guess that the "new" rEFInd installation has been customized by Pop_OS and is not located at `\EFI\refind\` directory within the ESP, but in a distribution-specific directory like `\EFI\pop_os\` or something. Alternatively, the Pop_OS installer might have created a second ESP.

---

Typically, the installation of a bootloader is a two-step process: first, the regular installation of the bootloader package will provide the necessary files to the system disk. Then (either as an automated post-install action, or as a separate manual step), those files are used to install the actual working copy of the bootloader into the ESP (or in legacy BIOS systems, embedded into the MBR and the no-man's-land gap between the MBR and the first partition).

When you removed your Mint installation, only the first part was destroyed along with the Mint system partition. But because the ESP is designed to be shared betweeen any and all installed OSs, and you clearly did not damage your Windows installation in the process, you did not remove the ESP. So the old copy of rEFInd and its configuration were preserved on the ESP, in the `EFI\refind\` directory where the Mint had originally installed it.

Often, the ESP will be mounted as `/boot/efi` in Linux, but this may vary between distributions. And if you have multiple disks with an ESP on each disk, or even multiple ESPs on the same disk, the installer may have become confused.

Assuming that the ESP that is being used at boot initially (and contains the "new" rEFInd) is the same as the ESP mounted to `/boot/efi` on Pop_OS, you should find the "old" rEFInd at `/boot/efi/EFI/refind/refind_x64.efi` as viewed from Pop_OS. The location of the "new" rEFInd should also be apparent after seeing the `sudo efibootmgr -v` output.

Note that the "old" rEFInd says:

```
Boot EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi from 798 MiB FAT volume
```

and not `... from EFI system partition`. That suggests you may now have two ESPs on your system, and probably only one of them will be automatically mounted in Linux.

Also, note that the UEFI bootloader for Windows has the UEFI boot variable pathname of `EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi`. So if the ESP that is currently mounted at `/boot/efi` is the one that also contains the Windows bootloader, you should find it at `/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi`. If it's not there, it's probably on the "other ESP" on your system. You don't want to delete the Windows bootloader directory: it contains some files with information specific to your Windows installation, and the only easy way to recreate it is to use the "Repair boot" functionality on the Windows installation media.